# What does "('*') = '*' mean in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited maintenance of an in-house application along with a couple of views in our ERP system's database.

I have begun to suspect that my predecessor was drunk as a skunk when writing these views, or was making the queries deliberately complicated as a form job protection (if so, the joke is on me, because the guy quit).

One of the things that I find highly confusing about the views is that the WHERE-clause contains a sub-clause that looks a little bit like this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ...
OR ( (('*') IS NULL)
     AND Project.Invalid = 0
     AND ... )
OR ...
```

From my understanding, that `('*') IS NULL` part should basically be a no-op. Yet, when I comment that line out, the number of rows returned by the query jumps from 460 to ~350,000.

I am fairly confused by this, I would have expected no change at all in the number of results.
In the same query, another branch of the `WHERE`-clause contained a similar sub-clause, `((-255) IS NULL)`, and when I commented *that one* out, the number of results stayed the same.

What is going on here? Is there something funky going on, or am I missing something obvious?

Thank you very, very much for any input!!!

Comment: `('*') IS NULL` evaluates to false. Of course if you comment it out, the result changes. Try commenting out the whole OR part (that is also evaluated to false): `OR ( (('*') IS NULL)
     AND Project.Invalid = 0
     AND ... )`

Comment: Thank you very much! In retrospect, it is so obvious! ;-) I am going to facepalm myself for a while...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`('*') IS NULL` evaluates to false. As a result the `OR` part also evaluates to false. We can use the simple rule:

```
(FALSE AND Something AND Something_Else AND ... ) 
= FALSE
```

Of course as a result, if you comment out `(('*') IS NULL)` the result changes.

Try commenting out the whole `OR` part:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ...
-- OR ( (('*') IS NULL)
--      AND Project.Invalid = 0
--      AND ... )
OR ...
```

This should have no effect, due to the other rule:

```
(FALSE OR Something OR Something_Else OR ... ) 
= 
(Something OR Something_Else OR ... )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After removing all the dead branches from the WHERE clause, the query is roughly 30% of its former size. ;-)